# Is it possible to apply query rules to a LINQ to SQL association list?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We have standard db columns in all our tables, one of which is a boolean 'Active'. So instead of physically deleting the data, we just set the Active property to false.

This causes a problem when we use association properties, like the below relationship:

User.Company.Name (Users.CompanyId -> Companies.Id)

**If the Company in question was flagged as Active = false, would it be possible to write a generic rule in my data access layer to exclude items in the list when the value of the Active property is false?**

Currently we just have a vanilla Linq to Sql configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Linq-to-SQL (more with EF) but I imagine this would be tackled if, say, all your classes that have that property share a common interface, for example:

```
public interface IHasActive
{
    bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can implement an extension method:

```
public static class IHasActiveExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ExcludeInactive<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        where T : IHasActive
    {
        return query.Where(m => m.Active);
    }
}
```